# Отличие веб-сервера и REST веб-сервиса

Tags: веб-сервер, веб-служба

Веб-сервер - это сервер реализующий http протокол.

Веб-сервис - это технология для взаимодействия между системами. REST подход подразумевает передачу представления ресурсов, это может быть HTML,JSP,XML.

Вопрос: в чем отличие REST веб-сервиса от веб-сервера? Можно ли сказать, что 
REST веб-сервис = веб-сервер + возможность взаимодействия с другими системами.

Comment: Всё таки это два разных определения и нельзя их объединять в одно понятие.Общее у них только то, что любой веб-сервис не может работать без веб-сервера. А вот веб-сервер без веб-сервиса работает без проблем.

Comment: В чем отличие tcp от http?

Comment: @vp_arth, tcp протокол транспортного уровня, http протокол прикладного уровня. Грубо говоря первый служит для доставки пакетов, второй служит для осмысленного стандартизированного общения между клиентом и сервером.

Comment: @DanielOlivo, ахха, это был риторический вопрос)

Comment: @vp_arth, а я повелся ((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это сравнение теплого с мягким.

REST это архитектура для реализации api.

Веб-сервер же реализует http протокол.

В общем случае REST сервис находится за веб-сервером и является частью бекенда.